# Cors policy Issue Laravel youtube apache

Tags: laravel, header, xmlhttprequest, cors, wildcard

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I am using laravel 5.1 when i use youtube embedded iframe i receive this error. i am unable to find where is access control allow origin is passing a * as wildcard. can anybody help please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding below lines of code in your `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```